# PHP associative array parse error that only affects some machines

Tags: php

This code fails on some machines:

```
// Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' ...
return json_encode(self::GenerateSomeAssociativeArray($meta_file)["list"]);
```

but this effectively identical version works on all machines:

```
$foo = self::GenerateSomeAssociativeArray($meta_file);
return json_encode($foo['list']);
```

I assume it's a versioning issue, but I'm unable to find information on the difference, probably because I'm unfamiliar with the terminology to search.

Comment: You'll find it in this list of syntax/feature additions: http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first example you gave is for PHP 5.4 and supposedly higher.
See the following PHP 5.4 release announcement:

http://php.net/releases/5_4_0.php

```
<?php
// Example #8 Array dereferencing

function getArray() {
    return array(1, 2, 3);
}

// on PHP 5.4
$secondElement = getArray()[1];

// previously
$tmp = getArray();
$secondElement = $tmp[1];

// or
list(, $secondElement) = getArray();
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Versions of PHP prior to 5.4 don't allow the array indexing operator (`[]`) to be applied to anything other than a variable.

Yes, really.